# App Engine Built-ins Python 2.7

Tags: google-app-engine

I am converting to Python 2.7

In doing so the Built-in in yaml is being invalid

application: nameofapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

builtins:
- datastore_admin: on
- remote_api: on

The above is the entry in my YAML file and the builtins: section errors - What am I doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the 1.6.1 release notes:

> WARNING: Starting with the 1.6.2 release of the experimental Python
>   2.7 runtime, the mapreduce and datastore_admin builtins will not be supported.

The "right" way to use the datastore_admin tool is to enable it through the admin console instead of enabling the builtin in your app.yaml.

[Credit](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-python/L0z_sONQHc0)

Comment: I have done that and nothing appears when I go into the datastore_admin screen.  What else do I have to do?

Comment: @TrevorBranch not sure if this is the case but if you are using safari that is a known bug. try to open it using chrome.

Comment: I am in chrome and not working. Just tried IE and it works.  Thanks